# Execute Cloud function when table is updated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, event-arc

This is my first question here, so I'm trying to do all politely :)

I have a table in BigQuery, where data is inserted every day. The insertion time is different every day, some days is 5 minutes later but other days can be 2 hours later.

After that, I have to execute a cloud function, which, at the moment, is scheduled with a cron (Cloud Scheduler --> Pub/Sub).

I want to execute the cloud function just after the insertion of data in my table. Do you have any tips?

I have tried with Eventarc and 2nd generation Cloud Functions. Using this trigger: `google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.InsertTable`, but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Can you go to Cloud Logging and see if you find a "jobCompleted" entry? If so, you can base your subsequent processing following this log entry (you might have have to refine the log filtering to be sure to catch only the event that update your table, and not the others). If you don't know how to achieve that, I will be able to provide more guidance (tip: sink to PubSub)

Comment: Hello @guillaumeblaquiere! First of all, what a coincidence! I work in the retail sector, too.

I'm closing the question. Finally, we are integrating this procedure into an Airflow program, so the problem is solved. Thanks for your help :)